# Using inputs and outputs of a generator function

Tags: javascript, caching, generator

I was experimenting using genrator functions, and I came up with the following generator. It works, but I don't understand how it is able to use the yield input, process it and use the same yield statement to output the result...

How does the program flow work?

```js
//My caching Generator
function* cache(){
 let input, output, cache = {};
 while(true){
  input = yield output;
  //Some code...
  if(input in cache){
   output = cache[input];
   console.log("Old Value: "+output);
  }else{
   output = f(input);
   cache[input] = output;
   console.log("New Value: "+output);
  }
 }
}

//Some expensive function:
function f(x){
 return x.split("").reverse().join("");
}

const c = cache();
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("this is lost").value);
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("Hello").value);
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("World").value);
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("Hello").value);
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("Stackoverflow").value);
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield? Could you be more specific about what you don't understand in the current code?

Comment: Yes, I read that. I would expect c.next() to return yield the result of the last input, since that is that value, that output holds...

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying you expect, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try:

```
const c = cache();
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("this is lost").value);
```

This assigns `c` with an iterator function for `cache` (first line) and then runs `cache` initially until the first `yield expression`, so basically this code:

```
let input, output, cache = {};
yield output;
```

`output` is `undefined`, so `undefined` is returned from the first `next()` call. Note, however, that the argument (`"this is lost"`) is **not** passed into this `yield`. It'd be passed into the `yield` where the previous execution was halted. As there was no previous run of `c.next` it is, indeed, lost.

In the next run:

```
console.log("Return value: "+ c.next("Hello").value);
```

the following code is executed:

```
input = "Hello"; // the yield is substituted with the next() argument here!
//Some code...
if(input in cache){ // false
  output = cache[input];
  console.log("Old Value: "+output);
} else {
  output = f(input);
  cache[input] = output;
  console.log("New Value: "+output);
}
yield output // "olleH"
```

The function resumes at the exact line where it was halted before and the `yield output` gets replaced with the `next()` argument. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) says:

> Calling the next() method with an argument will resume the generator function execution, replacing the yield expression where execution was paused with the argument from next().